# Configuring Shibboleth SAML 2.0 with ADFS 3.0 with Fedration Errors

Tags: centos7, adfs, shibboleth, saml

I'm trying to configure ADFS 3.0 and SAML 2.0. Currently, I get this error whenever I restart `shibd` and `httpd`.

```
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 2702, message: grammar not found for namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 2702, message: attribute 'ServiceDisplayName' is not declared for element 'RoleDescriptor'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 3893, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:ClaimTypesRequested'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 24931, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:TargetScopes'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26031, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:ApplicationServiceEndpoint'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26285, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26473, message: element 'fed:ClaimTypesRequested' is not allowed for content model '(Signature?,Extensions?,KeyDescriptor*,Organization?,ContactPerson*)'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26848, message: grammar not found for namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26848, message: attribute 'ServiceDisplayName' is not declared for element 'RoleDescriptor'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 28026, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:TokenTypesOffered'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 28193, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:ClaimTypesOffered'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 49245, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:SecurityTokenServiceEndpoint'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 49941, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 50129, message: element 'fed:TokenTypesOffered' is not allowed for content model '(Signature?,Extensions?,KeyDescriptor*,Organization?,ContactPerson*)'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.XML : error while loading resource (https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml): XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
2016-11-07 12:49:08 WARN OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.XML : adjusted reload interval to 1800 seconds
2016-11-07 12:49:08 CRIT OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.XML : maintaining existing configuration, error reloading resource (https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml): XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
```

My current configuration in `shibbolet2.xml`

```
<!-- ADFS Extension -->
<OutOfProcess>
    <Extensions>
        <Library path="/usr/lib64/shibboleth/adfs.so" fatal="true"/>
    </Extensions>
</OutOfProcess>
<InProcess logger="native.log" checkSpoofing="true">
    <Extensions>
        <Library path="/usr/lib64/shibboleth/adfs-lite.so" fatal="true"/>
    </Extensions>
</InProcess>
<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap applicationId="default">
        <Host name="c-app01">
            <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
        </Host>
    </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>
<ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://c-app01.contoso.com/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata.xml"
                     REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id">
    <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" relayState="ss:mem"
             checkAddress="false" handlerSSL="true" cookieProps="https">
        <!-- Putting another SSO here will make shibd fail. There should only be one SSO. -->
        <SSO>
            SAML2 SAML1 ADFS
        </SSO>
        <!-- SAML and local-only logout. -->
        <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>
        <!-- Extension service that generates "approximate" metadata based on SP configuration. -->
        <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata.xml" signing="false"/>
        <!-- Status reporting service. -->
        <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1 ::1"/>
        <!-- Session diagnostic service. -->
        <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="false"/>
        <!-- JSON feed of discovery information. -->
        <Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed"/>
    </Sessions>
    <Errors supportContact="root@localhost"
        helpLocation="/about.html"
        styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>
    <MetadataProvider type="XML" validate="true"
        uri="https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
        reloadInterval="7200">
      <DiscoveryFilter type="Blacklist" matcher="EntityAttributes" trimTags="true"
        attributeName="http://macedir.org/entity-category"
        attributeNameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
        attributeValue="http://refeds.org/category/hide-from-discovery" />
    </MetadataProvider>
    <!-- Example of locally maintained metadata. -->
    <AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="attribute-map.xml"/>
    <!-- Use a SAML query if no attributes are supplied during SSO. -->
    <AttributeResolver type="Query" subjectMatch="true"/>
    <!-- Default filtering policy for recognized attributes, lets other data pass. -->
    <AttributeFilter type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-policy.xml"/>
    <!-- Simple file-based resolver for using a single keypair. -->
    <CredentialResolver type="File" key="c-app01.contoso.com.key" certificate="c-app01.contoso.com.pem"/>
</ApplicationDefaults>
<!-- Policies that determine how to process and authenticate runtime messages. -->
<SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="security-policy.xml"/>
<!-- Low-level configuration about protocols and bindings available for use. -->
<ProtocolProvider type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="protocols.xml"/>
```

Apache Configuration `/etc/httpd/conf.d/shib.conf`

```
LoadModule mod_shib /usr/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_24.so

ShibCompatValidUser Off

<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
  SetHandler shib
  AuthType None
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

How do I remove those `fed` errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ADFS, these errors are coming from the ADFS Endpoints.

```
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 3893, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:ClaimTypesRequested'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 24931, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:TargetScopes'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26031, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:ApplicationServiceEndpoint'
2016-11-07 12:49:08 ERROR XMLTooling.ParserPool : error on line 1, column 26285, message: no declaration found for element 'fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint'
```

So, I just had to disable the unused Endpoints in ADFS Management > Service > Endpoints. Then, it removed the errors afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you had find the solution, but I've just encountered the same situation, and I have a workaround : In your shibboleth2.xml file, change the "validate" parameter to "false", like this :

```
<MetadataProvider type="XML" validate="false" file="/etc/shibboleth/FederationMetadata.xml"/>
```

In my case, I'm able to be redirected on the login page of the Idp, and send back to my application.